# ArrayList declaration and handling

Tags: java, arraylist

I often use ArrayList in my Java software and i insist that the program has to be as clean as possible.

I have this ambiguity in ArrayList variable declaration and usage.

So, what is, among these three ArrayList usages, the correct way that I have to choose?

**CASE 1:**

```
List<Object> l = some_function();
```

**CASE 2:**

```
    List<Object> l  = new ArrayList<Object>();
    l = some_function();
    //staff
    l.clear()
```

**CASE 3:**

```
 List<Object> l = null;
 l = some_function();
 //staff
 l.clear()
```

**Function:**

```
List<Object> some_function(){
List<Object> list = new AyyarList<Object>();
//Staff
return list;
}
```

**My question about the function is:**
Does java clear the list variable automatically, or have I clean it by using `clear()` API and how then?
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, case 1 is better. 2nd case create an unnecessary `ArrayList` object, which will be lost when you assign the method return value.

> Does java clear the list variable automatically, or have I clean it by
>   using clean() API and how then?

Java won't clear your list, you have to clear it, check the API, [`ArrayList#clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29)

> how can clear the list manually if it is declared inside the function
>   and i should use it later outside the function(its outputs)

You have to assign the returned list to a temporary list, then you can clear the list.

```
List<Object> returnedList = some_function();
 //stuff
 returnedList.clear()
```

---

```
List<Object> some_function() {
     List<Object> list = new AyyarList<Object>();
     //Stuff
     return list;
}
```

Comment: But `list` is declared inside `some_function`!

Comment: You just changed your answer!

Comment: @HoussemBdr : I don't get your above comment question?

Comment: I think he wants to know if `list` is "cleared" by Java's garbage collection automatically. I don't think he is really talking about the `.clear()` function here (although he uses it himself as well).

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran how can clear the list manually if it is declared inside the function and i should use it later outside the function(its output)

Comment: @HoussemBdr The `clear()` function removes all elements from a `List`. Is that what you mean, and if so, why should that be done automatically?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers trying to be more clear:) , inside the function i have created a List of Objects and this List will its output so when can I clear it manually?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran checked, so `list` will disappear from memory after that??

Comment: @HoussemBdr : No, you just passed the reference of it to outside the method, I won't disappeared.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran got it : )

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, case 1 is better.

```
List<Object> l = some_function();
```

There is no need for the second case in which you assign a value to the variable then overwrite it.

I would not recommend you using clear unless you need to re-use the `l` variable. Because the memory is cleared asynchronously by the Garbage collector, and not directly by such library functions as clear(). clear would only null them all out, and update the ArrayList state accordingly.

So either way, the memory will only be cleared by the garbage collector.